# Wolfram Alpha evaluates $\operatorname{arccot}(-\sqrt{3}/3)$ as $-\pi/3$ instead of $2\pi/3$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Evaluating 
$$\operatorname{arccot}(-\sqrt{3}/3)$$

I tried this in Wolfram Alpha trying to verify a solution of mine, and I was expecting to get $2 \pi / 3$ but it says $-\pi/3$.

Does it consider the range of $\operatorname{arccot}$ something different than the usual $(0, \pi)$?

If so... isn't it causing quite some confusion?

Comment: WA uses that the range of arccot is $\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right)$.

Comment: Only to those who haven’t read the documentation.

Comment: @amd You are so smart... A true genius.

Comment: @John Doe Hm... What is arccotan 0 then?! Something does not make sense here. This interval cannot be the range, I think.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%280%29&t=crmtb01

Comment: @saulspatz That is what I meant. How can the range be the open interval from - pi/2 to pi/2 if arccotan from 0 is pi/2 ?!  Something does not make sense here.

Comment: It's obviously a typo.  The range is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2].$  No big deal.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccotan%20x Apparently WA has some strange idea about arccotan. See the range they describe here. At least now I understand the idea WA has about arccotan. But I think it is quite weird and confusing.

Comment: It is not a typo, the zero is not in the range too.

Comment: And I was told that I don't read the docs...

Comment: @saulspatz Officially in math the range is (0,π). At least AFAIK. So this whole WA implementation is quite weird. The graph which WA provides is also weird and more complicated than needed. The interval which you said is the range namely (-pi/2, pi/2] is incorrect too as it includes the zero.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to complain to Steve Wolfram

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah :) I was thinking exactly that.